# Wrong hyperref links in TOC for manually set alphanumeric section numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, hyperref, numbering

I wish to have chapter appendices in the sense that there are sections at the end of chapters with `\Alph` numbering. My macros `\chapterappendix`, `\mainchapter` and `\mainappendix` work in so far as they switch section numbering in the document and TOC exactly how I would like it.

However, `hyperref` links in the TOC for the appendix sections point to wrong targets, namely to sections with `\arabic` numbering, see below.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter

\newcommand*\mainchapter{%
    \if@twoside\cleardoubleoddpage\else\clearpage\fi
    \setcounter{page}{1}%
    \renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}} }

\newcommand*{\chapterappendix}{%
    \if@twoside\cleardoubleoddpage\else\clearpage\fi
    \setcounter{section}{0}%
    \renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\Alph{section}} }

\newcommand*{\mainappendix}{%
    \if@openright\cleardoubleoddpage\else\clearpage\fi
    \stepcounter{chapter}\setcounter{section}{0}%
    \renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Alph{section}} 
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{%
        \protect\nonumberline Appendix}{}{}} }

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\mainchapter
\chapter{MainChap1}
\section{MainSec1.1}
\chapterappendix
\section{AppSec1.A}

\mainchapter
\chapter{MainChap2}
\section{MainSec2.1}
\chapterappendix
\section{AppSec1.A}

\mainappendix
\section{AppSecA}

\end{document}
```

Content of `.toc` file:

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}MainChap1}{1}{chapter.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}MainSec1.1}{1}{section.1.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.A}AppSec1.A}{3}{section.1.1}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}MainChap2}{1}{chapter.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.1}MainSec2.1}{1}{section.2.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.A}AppSec1.A}{3}{section.2.1}
\contentsline {chapter}{\nonumberline Appendix}{}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {A}AppSecA}{5}{section.3.1}
```

How can I tell `hyperref` to link, for example, to section `section.1.A` instead of `section.1.1`?

**EDIT**

I have stated more precisely that my problem includes switching back and forth between appendix and non-appendix mode. The MWE is more complete now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem with regards to incorrect jumping from the ToC is corrected by using the [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) `hypertexnames` option, together with an update of `hyperref`'s `\thesection` equivalent (`\theHsection`).

I was unable to correct the page anchors without some hacking using a `plainpages` "page series", thanks to [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref,etoolbox}
\hypersetup{
  hypertexnames,
  plainpages
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\mainchapter{%
  \if@twoside\cleardoubleoddpage\else\clearpage\fi
  \setcounter{page}{1}%
  \renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}%
  \renewcommand*{\@pageseries}{chapter.\thechapter.}% Add a page series to keep hyperref happy
}

\newcommand*{\chapterappendix}{%
  \if@twoside\cleardoubleoddpage\else\clearpage\fi
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \renewcommand*{\thesection}{\thechapter.\Alph{section}}%
  \renewcommand*{\theHsection}{\thesection}%
}

\newcommand*{\mainappendix}{%
  \if@openright\cleardoubleoddpage\else\clearpage\fi
  \stepcounter{chapter}%\setcounter{section}{0} <- done automatically
  \renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{%
    \protect\nonumberline Appendix}{}{}}%
}

\patchcmd{\Hy@EveryPageAnchor}% <cmd>
  {page.}% <search>
  {page.\@pageseries}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\newcommand{\@pageseries}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\mainchapter
\chapter{MainChap1}
\section{MainSec1.1}
\chapterappendix
\section{AppSec1.A}

\mainchapter
\chapter{MainChap2}
\section{MainSec2.1}
\chapterappendix
\section{AppSec1.A}

\mainappendix
\section{AppSecA}

\end{document}
```